# How do I get the constellation types of satellites, when Android API level is less then 24?

Tags: android, gps

`GnssStatus` is added in Api level 24, we can use `getConstellationType(int satIndex)` to retrieves the constellation type of the satellite at the specified index.
When Android API level is less then 24, How do I get the constellation types of satellites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, I found an open source project called GpsTest on GitHub. [Here is GpsTest address.](https://github.com/barbeau/gpstest)Even if android api level is less then 24, we can get the constellation type of the every satellites in this app.They use an industry-standard official mapping of satellites to “PRN” values. There are specific implementation methods and detailed explanations in the source code.